# Need to join two tables where all data is correct in table A

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two tables with the same format. They look like this:

[image]

**All the data in table A is correct**. It contains 158.000 EAN numbers. In table B there is about 5.000 EAN numbers. There are some EAN numbers in table B however, that is not in table A. I need to make a new table that has all data from table A + the EAN numbers from table B that is not in table A.

At first I did a union and then a union all. That's how I found out that there were duplicate values. Table B only contains NULL values for MeterNumberOfDigits, MeterConversionFactor and MeterUnitType. I don't know how to make the join correctly so that I retain the info in these lines.

Comment: try distinct with column name

Comment: So why not use UNION ALL? Or are there data inconsistency. Why two tables with more or less the same data???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following query will give you all the records from `table A` and records from `tableB` which contains the `EANno` not found in `table A`:

```
select [Your column list] from tableA A
inner join tableB B
on A.EANno = B.EANno

union all

select [Your column list] from tableB B
where B.EANno not in (select distinct EANno from tableA)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select EAN from A union select EAN from B.
```

union all will keep the duplicate value, union just keep
 the distinct value.

if you do

```
select * from A union select * from B
```

the same EAN rows doesn't mean the same row, they maybe different on other columns

I hope this can help you